# DOM Manipulation for parent and child div at the same time

Tags: javascript, dom

My HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <ul id="child"></ul>
</div>
<button>click</button
```

My JS:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var child = document.getElementById('child');
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    parent.innerHTML = 'value1';
    child.innerHTML = 'value2';
});
```

I am trying to add values via JS for the `parent` and `child` div. But when I click `button` the nested `ul` tags disappear and my DOM only shows the `parent` value. Trying to understand what is happening here. Is this a flaw in the way I have structured the HTML? If this is expected behavior, how can I fix it without changing the HTML tags relationship?

Expected result should be: value1 and value2. Right now it only shows value1.

Comment: Well yeah, you're setting the HTML content of the parent.  That will remove any HTML currently inside the parent.  Are you trying to add text before/after the child element?  Your HTML is fine, but the corrections to your JS depend on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I would put the actual text you want to change in it's own element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are overwiting instead of appending.
If you want to add to an already existing element, you should be using [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) and [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) instead.

What [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) does is transcribing the markup to a new one *(which means obviously over-writing any previously contained markup)*.

**In summary, your code does work as expected. The issue is, you are trying to apply one method, while trying to achieve something different.**

Comment: this is the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is expected.
`innerHTML` replaces the insides of the element, thus, the child would not exist

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use HTML DOM `insertAdjeacentHTML()` Method instead of `innerHTML` for parent element. This method inserts a text as HTML, into a specified position. Legal position values are: "`afterbegin`", "`afterend`", "`beforebegin`" and "`beforeend`".

```js
var parent = document.getElementById( 'parent' ),
    child = document.getElementById( 'child' ),
    button = document.querySelector( 'button' );

button.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  parent.insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', 'value1' );
  child.innerHTML = 'value2'
} )
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <ul id="child"></ul>
</div>
<button>click</button>
```